# 'Cannot import name games'

Tags: python, pygame, importerror, livewires

I'm a beginner and so far I have about 3 hours invested installing pygame( ie getting the python interpreter to accept 'from livewires import games, color' to check both 'pygame' and 'livewires' have installed).

However, when I ran my first source code I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python31/Coding/pygame.py", line 4, in <module>
    from livewires import games
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\livewires\games.py", line 57, in <module>
    import pygame, pygame.image, pygame.mixer, pygame.font, pygame.transform
  File "C:/Python31/Coding\pygame.py", line 4, in <module>
    from livewires import games
ImportError: cannot import name games
>>>
```

Why might this be happening? Does anyone have some pointers? I don't have any hours left to figure it out myself, what with a full-time job and life matters.

Thanks,

Dave

Code:

```
# New graphics window
# Demo's creating a graphics  window

from livewires import games

# initialize graphics screen
games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)

# start mainloop
games.screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: If I run the identical code (incl batch file) supplied as part of the learning materials, it works. Yet mine won't. I have both sets of source code sitting in a file on my desktop.

Comment: @Michael Johnson you naming your script `pygame.py` , rename it to anything else.

Comment: Wow! Thank-you. Now I'm going to go off and read why that is not a good idea. Not that I'll make that mistake again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You naming your code script `pygame.py` which rises a conflict with `pygame` library.  Change the name and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to `import` from `livrewires` and in your current working directory there is a script named `pygame.py`.

Rename the `pygame.py` script to something else.